# Mongoose findOne function is not working with authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am working on a model here:

```
// user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Define collection and schema for Users
let User = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    emailaddress: String,
    password: String,
  },
  {
    collection: 'users'
  }
);

// authenticate input against database documents
User.statics.authenticate = ((emailaddress, password, callback) => {
  User.findOne({ emailaddress: emailaddress })
      .exec(function(error, user){
        if(error){
          return callback(error)
        } else if (!user){
          console.log('User not found!');
        }
        bycrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result){
          if(result === true){
            return callback(null, user);
          } else {
            return callback();
          }
        })
      })
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

As you can see on my model I put the User.statics.authenticate on my codes to do some authentication. And then on my login.js route file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../../database/index');
const axios = require('axios');
const User = require('../../database/models/user');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('hi there this is working login get');
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var emailaddress = req.body.emailaddress;
  var password = req.body.password;


  if( emailaddress && password ){
    User.authenticate(emailaddress, password, function(err, user){
       if(err || !user){
         console.log('Wrong email or password!');
       } else {
         req.session.userId = user._id;
         return res.redirect('/');
       }
    });
  } else {
     console.log('both fields are required...');
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

I called the function and then `User.authenticate` function and also I created the route for root w/c is the sample that I want to protect and redirect the user after login:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if(! req.session.userId ){
    console.log('You are not authorized to view this page!');
  }

  User.findById(req.session.userId)
      .exect((err, user) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          res.redirect('/');
        }
      })
});
```

Upon clicking submit on my react form it returns this error:

```
TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
    at Function.User.statics.authenticate (/Users/mac/Documents/monkeys/database/models/user.js:35:8)
```

I checked the [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) documentation and it seems I am using the right syntax.Any idea what am I doing wrong here?  Please help! Sorry super beginner here!

PS. I've already installed and set up the basic express session too.

UPDATES:

I remove the arrow function from my call and use `this.model.findOne` but still get the typerror findOne is not a function

```
// authenticate input against database documents
User.statics.authenticate = function(emailaddress, password, callback){
  this.model.findOne({ emailaddress: emailaddress })
      .exec(function(error, user){
        if(error){
          return callback(error)
        } else if (!user){
          console.log('User not found!');
        }
        bycrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result){
          if(result === true){
            return callback(null, user);
          } else {
            return callback();
          }
        })
      })
};
```

Comment: `User` is NOT a mongoose model. It's a "Schema". You want a "model" i.e `mongoose.mdoel("User", new Schema({ ... }))`. All in the documentation.

Comment: @NeilLunn: can you expand more really need to figure this out?

Comment: Instead of using `const User = require('../../database/models/user');
`

Can you try to do : `const mongoose = require('mongoose'); const User = mongoose.model('User');` and see if this works ?

Comment: This line then, inside the `authenticate`: `User.findOne({ emailaddress: emailaddress })` The variable "in scope" at that time is the "schema". For a "static" it really should be `this.model.findOne(...)` instead. So `this.model` instead of `User` which is the "schema".

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

Comment: Because you cannot use "arrow"  `=>` functions" here either. Needs to be a regular `function()`, just like it says in the documentation. Using the "arrow" changes the context of what `this` means to where this actually gets called.

Comment: Ok I removed all the arrow function and still got this: `TypeError: User.findOne is not a function`

Comment: Show what you actually did as additional detail in your question, because you still seem to be missing a step. Also use the `@` thingy when responding to people who comment. I can't watch this all night and people only get notified when they are the **only** res ponder. Using `@` makes sure we "get the message".

Comment: @NeilLunn updated my question above. Sorry for not tagging you whenever I am responding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169842/discussion-between-marc-solva-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: Oh sorry. Just `this` and not `this.model`. Reason is because when this gets attached to the "model" the `this` actually refers to that instance.

Comment: Now I got this: TypeError: `User.findById(...).exect is not a function
    at router.get (/Users/mac/Documents/monkeys/server/routes/index.js:26:8)`

Comment: Nevermind I change the exect to exec

Comment: @Neil Lunn res.redirect('/'); doesnt work? how can I redirect my user once verified the email and password?

Comment: @MarcSolva That is not the question you asked. We aren't here to debug your application. The error you posted the question about is the point which I explained you are doing incorrectly. You should really be posting a "new question" for different issues. And really you should be following the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting all your code. You're asked to do that for the very reason that it should prompt you into basic debugging and test cases before you even post.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the heads up. It's not my intention to let you debug my application. I am just asking for the sake of our comments convo. Anyway appreciate your time man! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

findOne is a method on your User model, not your user model instance. It provides its async results to the caller via callback:

```
User.findOne({field:'value'}, function(err, doc) { ... });
```

Comment: I actually followed this convention if you will look at my codes.